# Contravariant parameters?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, c#-4.0, contravariance

This is probably a stupid question but, I have a method I use to make the syntax of a page a little more easy to read

```
    public void Do(Delegate method, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    {
        this.Window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method, DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
```

then I can write

```
        Do(new Action(() =>
        {
            //DoStuff()
        }));
```

However, I'd like to move the Action up into the Do Method  so I can write more Simply:

```
        Do(() =>
        {
            //DoStuff()
        }));
```

But I'm a bit sure how to write the contravariant parameter to do the Do Method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas are untyped, so this is not possible.

If you don't care about method-arguments,  which appears to be the case, why not change the method signature to :

```
public void Do(Action method,
               DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
```

Then, the second sample will work fine since the compiler will be able to implicitly convert the lambda to an `Action`.

If you really want to accept an instance of *any* delegate-type that represents a method that takes no arguments, you'll have to stick to something like what you currently have.